# Angularjs how to conditionally check a checkbox based upon existence of repeat element in another list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

as a very new angularjs user with a cshtml page, during page load of a modal window, I am trying to check a repeating checkbox if it exists in another list. the code below is conceptual:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="analysisType in analysisTypes|limitTo:12 | limitTo: -6">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-class="{'checked' : project.analysisTypes.indexOf(analysisType) != -1}" />
    {{analysisType.name}}
</li>
```

specifically, if analysisType is found in project.analysisTypes array, I would like to check the checkbox. I am nearly certain that it is possible, but can't figure out how.

analysisTypes and project both exist on the $scope, so that data is available.

or maybe the solution is to bind the checkboxes directly to project.analysisTypes, but I still need to be able to dynamically render the domain checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'indexOf' can't be used to find the first matched object of an array in this way([simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9c50jj9y/)). You should find it by searching specific and unique attribute of the object, e.g., id.

Here is my example:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="analysisType in analysisTypes">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-class="{'checked':isExist(analysisType.id)!=-1}" ng-checked="isExist(analysisType.id)!=-1"/>
            {{analysisType.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.analysisTypes = [{id:1,name:"typeA"},{id:2,name:"typeB"},{id:3,name:"typeC"}];

    $scope.project = {analysisTypes:[{id:2,name:"typeB"}]};

    $scope.isExist = function(id){
        return $scope.project.analysisTypes.map(function(type){return type.id;}).indexOf(id);
    }
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/43fjx5zz/1/).

Please note: **Array.prototype.map** and **Array.prototype.indexOf** only can be used in IE9+. You need to add some polyfill if you have browser supporting concern.

Answer (score 5):

you could use the ng-checked directive to check your input when the condition return true  or just bind your input with a ng-model.

try something like that

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="project.analysisTypes.indexOf(analysisType) != -1" />
```